# Using ASP.NET Core MVC cookie based authentication with custom user tables in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

**I have my own tables for Authentication:**
Users
Roles
UserRoles

I am am trying to figure out what the best way to implement custom authentication with ASP.NET Core MVC would be. I do not want to use the built in UserManager, RoleManager, etc. I prefer creating my own. Can I somehow still tap into the cookie based authentication and use all of the ASP.NET Authorization helper tags without using asp.net identity?

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe I want something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Comment: How do you plan to hash and store password?

Comment: @Win I am going to use blowflish encryption with salt.

Comment: @Win because I have been trying to figure out ASP.NET Identity for years and I am sick of not understanding every single part of it. I would rather implement my own auth just like the good old days. It is most likely my problem for not being able to read the documentation and pick up on it, but I cant stand Entity Framework / ASP.NET Identity. I am aware that ASP.NET Identity can be used without EF but just seems like a pain. Plus my ultimate goal would be to use IdentityServer at some point to auth my client apps and apps. Just not ready for that yet.

Comment: @Win I feel like this stuff isn't rocket science. I prefer understanding 100% of what I build so I try to limit as much third party use as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been trying to figure out ASP.NET Identity for years and I am
>   sick of not understanding every single part of it. I would rather
>   implement my own auth just like the good old days. It is most likely
>   my problem for not being able to read the documentation and pick up on
>   it, but I cant stand Entity Framework / ASP.NET Identity. I am aware
>   that ASP.NET Identity can be used without EF but just seems like a
>   pain.

Well, if you decided to go that route, you can use ***Cookie Authentication Middleware***.

There are too many moving pieces, so I created [a sample project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit) in GitHub.

You can replace  [this LDAP Authentication](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L70) with your own Authentication mechanism. *[Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.NovellDirectoryLdap/LdapAuthenticationService.cs#L14)  is actual implementation.*

*The main reason I did not use ASP.NET Identity in some of my projects is we already have Active Directory in our organization.*

### [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Startup.cs#L123)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
   {
      OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
      {
         context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
         return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
      }
   },
   ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Int32.Parse(Configuration.GetSection(
       "AppSettings:CookieAuthentication:ExpireMinutes").Value)),
   AuthenticationScheme = Constants.AuthenticationScheme,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Common/AccessDenied"),
   AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
   AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Comment: thanks for this great response. I actually got it somewhat working for now but your post is going to help me fill in the blanks. So far I have it to the point where I am creating a cookie when a user logs in and I am able to access actions in controllers that have [Authorize] attribute on them. The next thing I am going to look into is how to set all of the UserRoles as Claims in the principal so they are stored in the cookie. Then I will be able to use those attributes too.

Comment: Now that the cookie is being stored in the browser do you know how I can access information from the cookie? For example, current logged in user etc. Typically I know I would get this information from the Identity Managers, but I am going to have to do it manually using HttpContext aren't I?

Comment: nevermind, it is as simple as HttpContext.User. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, we should use policy instead of role base. [Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Startup.cs#L72) is how I convert role claims to policy.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web.Common/UserSession.cs) is a wrapper class for HttpContext so that I can unit test controllers, and [here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L3) is how it is injected to view.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. If I have a database setup where there are Roles and Permissions, UserRoles and RolePermissions. Lets say user logs in and I retrieve the roles along with each role's permissions. When I create the principal to pass to the await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal); function how would you recommend I setup my Roles/Claims/Policys so that I can use the built in Authorize data attributes to check things at the permission level like... Only users that have the Permission EditCustomers can access the Edit Action, etc..

Comment: In my case would Permissions be claims or policies? And what would roles become?

Comment: Since most of us have role table, so we store authorized role as [claims](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web.Common/Security/SignInManager.cs#L30). Claims are then converted to [policy](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Startup.cs#L74). We then use [authorize attribute](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/DashboardController.cs#L8) to restrict access.

Comment: got it! but when would tasks/permissions come into play? I guess they aren't necessary anymore since authorize attributes are placed directly on the actions themselves. Lets say a Manager Role has the permissions Add Customer, Add Project, Edit Project. Is this something I should not use the built in Authorize attributes for and just use my own code to adjust the UI so that a user of that role's menu appears the way it should and they only can navigate to those pages?

Comment: Ideally, we should use Authorize Attribute, unless we have very complex authorization logic. For that case, we have to manually place that logic at the beginning to every action method like [this](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Areas/Admin/Controllers/CustomerController.cs#L765).